# How to add Number to Value in Textbox from DataGridView based on Keyword

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I'm currently working on a VB.NET Form that'll total how much each department costs based on pay of employees. All employees are in 1 Datagridview with columns specifying their names, position and wage. I'm trying to add textboxes to the side of the datagridview with the total cost of each department when you add up each individual's wage if they fall under it. Unfortunately I keep running into this error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
> Parameter name: index'

This is my first attempt and where the error originally popped up:

```
Try
  Dim Total As Decimal = 0
  For i As = 0 To Job_Viewer.Rows.Count Step +1 
    If Job_Viewer.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = "Design" Then 'The error appeared here
      Total_Design.Text = +Job_Viewer.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
    End If
  Next
Catch ex As Exception
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Thinking it could be the for statement that's be causing it, I tried:

```
Try
  Dim Total As Decimal = 0
  Dim i = 1
  If Job_Viewer.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = "Design" Then
    Total += Convert.ToDecimal(Job_Viewer.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)
    Total_Design.Text = Total.ToString
  End If
Catch ex As Exception
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

I'm not sure exactly what's wrong as according to vb.net, the way I've written the code is correct. Any advice?

Comment: Your posted code doesn't compile.  Avoid that by copying the code, not re-typing it.  `For i As = 0 To Job_Viewer.Rows.Count Step +1` : no need for the Step +1, it will already increment by one, but because it's zero-based, you have to do one less: `Row.Count - 1`

Comment: On my end it does? There was 1 line in there that wasn't mant to be there which I've just removed which could've been the issue. The whole thing was copy-pasted from my orgional code

Comment: This does not compile:  `For i As = 0 To`

Comment: If it was me, depending on how you have bound the source data to this DVG of course.  I would do the sums on the source data, Makes the whole process a ton simpler and can be done with a single line of code.  UI elements such as DVG are for UI interaction presenting data, processing should happen below that as much as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we count, we start with one so, `Count` starts at one. It tells us how many rows we have. Indexes in .net start at zero. If we have 7 rows, the indexes would be 0 to 6. In view of this be sure to remember the minus one when using `Count` in a `For` loop.

The `Value` property of a `Cell` in a DataGridView returns an `Object`. You must change the value to a `String` to compare it to a `String`. Likewise change the value to a `Decimal` to do addition.

You can avoid these errors by turning on Option Strict in Project Properties.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim Total As Decimal
    For i = 0 To Job_Viewer.Rows.Count - 1
        If Job_Viewer.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString = "Design" Then
            Total += CDec(Job_Viewer.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)
            Total_Design.Text = Total.ToString
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!! (Also as a beginner, that explanation of `count'`s relationship with `DataGridView` was great!!)